# "Polar" in polar coordinates

Tags: etymology

In mathematics, we use **polar coordinates**, I do not understand the reason of using the word "polar" here. What is the pole here? What does it have to do with the coordinates?

Comment: For your reference - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system. The reference point is called the *pole*

Comment: @BiscuitBoy Thank you very much, I am ashamed that it had a trivial answer that is widely available :)

Comment: No need to be ashamed. Just search before you post that will establish that you have worked your way before getting here! Cheers and welcome to EL&U :)

Comment: Locations on the surface of the Earth are expressed as polar coordinates.

Comment: The Wikipedia entry is, unfortunately, written by mathematicians and historians to impress other mathematicians and historians, and geeks like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this usage *polar* refers to a pole, meaning a pivot point or axis.  It comes to us through Old French from the Latin *polus* through the Greek *πόλος*.  (Note that this is different from the stake kind of pole, which comes to us from the Old English through the Latin *palus*.)

**Polar coordinates** refer the determination of any point *P* in the plane based on the length *r* of circular radius anchored at its axis point **O** (usually called the origin) and the angle *θ* that the radius makes with a horizontal line *x* through the axis point.

The polar regions of the earth are so called because they are near the axis points of an imaginary line around which the earth rotates.

[image]